# How to modify text style in java (or command prompt) through code

Tags: java, cmd, formatting

I have made a program which takes month number and year as input and displays the calendar of that particular month of the entered year. But I want to show the dates in any colour (or bold or anything which makes it look different) which are on Sundays. How do I do that in java. I have been searching for any library or code for this but cannot get it. This is the output which I get.

[image]

I don't think that my code is required here so I am not putting it. Any help or suggestion would be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom library named "JColor" that works on Linux, macOS, and Windows 10. It uses the ANSI codes and abstracts them using words instead of codes which is more intuitive.

**Download Link:**   https://github.com/dialex/JColor

**CODE**
Choose your format, colorize it, and print it:

```
System.out.println(colorize("Green text on blue", GREEN_TEXT(), BLUE_BACK()));
```

You can also define a format once, and reuse it several times:

```
AnsiFormat customFormat = new AnsiFormat(RED_TEXT(), YELLOW_BACK(), BOLD());
System.out.println(colorize("Something bad happened!", customFormat));
```